# Opcache ignoring certain settings in php.ini after httpd restart

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, opcache

I have recently updated my Centos 6, Apache server to php 5.6 from 5.4 and I'm attempting to configure opcache.

I have updated my opcache settings in `/etc/php.ini` to:

```
[opcache]
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
opcache.validate_timestamps = 0
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 12000
opcache.memory_consumption = 256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
```

And run `service httpd restart`.

The function `opcache_get_configuration()` tells me that it has changed the following:

```
 [opcache.validate_timestamps] =>
 [opcache.revalidate_freq] => 0
 [opcache.fast_shutdown] => 1
```

But the following remain unchanged:

```
 [opcache.memory_consumption] => 134217728 // or 128 mebibytes
 [opcache.interned_strings_buffer] => 8
 [opcache.max_accelerated_files] => 4000
```

How do I get opcache to take account of these preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had another file `/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini` that was explicitly setting the unchanged settings.

Apparently these were overriding my new `/etc/php.ini` settings.

Moving all my intended opcache config to `/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini` seems to have worked. Also there are some useful comments on what each setting does.